# What are the requirements for using `shfl` operations on AMD GPU using HIP C++?

Tags: concurrency, llvm, gpgpu, amd-gpu, hip

There is **AMD HIP C++** which is very similar to CUDA C++. Also AMD created **Hipify** to convert CUDA C++ to HIP C++ (Portable C++ Code) which can be executed on both nVidia GPU and AMD GPU: https://github.com/GPUOpen-ProfessionalCompute-Tools/HIP

- There are requirements to use `shfl` operations on nVidia GPU: https://github.com/GPUOpen-ProfessionalCompute-Tools/HIP/tree/master/samples/2_Cookbook/4_shfl#requirement-for-nvidia

> requirement for nvidia
>
> please make sure you have a **3.0 or higher compute capable** device in order to use warp shfl operations and add -gencode arch=compute=30, code=sm_30 nvcc flag in the Makefile while using this application.

- Also noted that HIP supports `shfl` for 64 wavesize (WARP-size) on AMD: https://github.com/GPUOpen-ProfessionalCompute-Tools/HIP/blob/master/docs/markdown/hip_faq.md#why-use-hip-rather-than-supporting-cuda-directly

> In addition, HIP defines portable mechanisms to query architectural features, and supports a larger **64-bit wavesize** which expands the return type for cross-lane functions like ballot and shuffle from 32-bit ints to 64-bit ints.

But which of AMD GPUs does support functions `shfl`, or does any AMD GPU support `shfl` because on AMD GPU it implemented by using Local-memory without hardware instruction register-to-register?

nVidia GPU required 3.0 or higher compute capable (CUDA CC), but what are the requirements for using `shfl` operations on AMD GPU using HIP C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Yes**, there are new instructions in GPU **GCN3** such as `ds_bpermute` and `ds_permute` which can provide the functionality such as `__shfl()` and even more
2. These `ds_bpermute` and `ds_permute` instructions use only route of Local memory (LDS 8.6 TB/s), but don't actually use Local memory, this allows to accelerate data exchange between threads: **8.6 TB/s < speed < 51.6 TB/s**: http://gpuopen.com/amd-gcn-assembly-cross-lane-operations/

> They use LDS hardware to route data between the 64 lanes of a wavefront, but they don’t actually write to an LDS location.

3. Also there are Data-Parallel Primitives (**DPP**) - is especially powerful when you can use it since an op can read registers of neighboring workitems directly. I.e. DPP can access to neighboring thread (workitem) at full speed **~51.6 TB/s**

http://gpuopen.com/amd-gcn-assembly-cross-lane-operations/

> now, most of the vector instructions can do cross-lane reading at full
>   throughput.

For example, `wave_shr`-instruction (Wavefront shift right) for **Scan algorithm**:

[image]

More about GCN3: https://github.com/olvaffe/gpu-docs/raw/master/amd-open-gpu-docs/AMD_GCN3_Instruction_Set_Architecture.pdf

> New Instructions
>
> - “SDWA” – Sub Dword Addressing allows access to bytes and words of VGPRs in VALU instructions.
> - “DPP” – Data Parallel Processing allows VALU instructions to access data from neighboring lanes.
> - DS_PERMUTE_RTN_B32, DS_BPERMPUTE_RTN_B32.
>
> ...
>
> DS_PERMUTE_B32 Forward permute. **Does not write any LDS memory**.